# GZip every file with Gradle 5.x and higher

Tags: gradle, gzip

We currently have a Gradle (v4.10.3) build script that compresses every static resource during build time. Below is a snippet of the code that we have:

```
tasks.register("gzipJsFiles") {
doLast {
    fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/classes/main/static/js", include: "**/*.min.js", exclude: "*.gz").eachWithIndex { file, index ->
        def dynamicTask = "gzipJs-$file.name"
        task "${dynamicTask}" (type: GzipJsTask) {
            source = file
            dest = Paths.get(file.absolutePath + ".gz").toFile()
        }
        tasks."$dynamicTask".execute()
    }
}}
```

Now, with the latest versions of Gradle, the Task.execute() is being deprecated.

Is there a way to achieve the GZip task, to zip every file in file tree, individually with the newer versions of Gradle (5.x or higher)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where the `GzipJsTask` comes from, but if it is the one from `gradle-js-plugin`, you can see from the [source code](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/eriwen/gradle/js/tasks/GzipJsTask.groovy) that it is simply a wrapper around some Ant commands. So instead of creating Gradle tasks dynamically at execution time, which is no longer possible, just run the commands directly:

```
doLast {
    fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/classes/main/static/js", include: "**/*.min.js", exclude: "*.gz").each { file ->
        ant.gzip(src: file.absolutePath, destfile: file.absolutePath + ".gz")
    }
}
```